# Eliminar el salto de linea que genera %s (String) en C

Tags: c, string

Buenas tardes y buenos días para todos y todas, tengo una mini duda y es que escribí un código en lenguaje C y me surgió un problemilla que para mi no es gran cosa pero me gustaría saber que piensan ustedes del tema.

cuando pongo

```
 printf("Los datos del paciente %s son : \n",paciente.nombre);
```

la salida es :

Los datos del paciente RAFA

son :

y aqui aparece el resto de los datos...

mi duda es que como le quito al string ese salto de linea que a mi no me hace gracia porque no deja que la salida sea agradable a la vista.
un saludo.

Mi humilde codigo:

```
int main(void)

{   //Creamos la variable paciente_1 a partir de la estructura 
     // PACIENTE;

    PACIENTE paciente_1;
    obtener_datos_paciente(&paciente_1);

    **printf("Los datos del paciente %s ",paciente_1.nombre);**
    mostrar_datos_paciente(&paciente_1);

}
```

Comment: En tu pregunta también te faltó mencionar como obtienes los datos (yo asumí que lo haces con fgets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Eliminar el salto de linea que genera %s (String) en C

La única manera para que ese salto de línea lo tenga la cadena, es porqué usaste [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Esto se debe, ya que la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) incluirá el salto de línea si no lee N-1(donde N es el tamaño máximo de caracteres). Por ejemplo, si el tamaño de la cadena `nombre` llega ser 5 y si el usuario ingresa `RAFA`, [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) leería 4 caracteres, como leyó los 4 caracteres, no incluirá el salto de línea, debido a que, el último espacio sería para el caracter nulo.

Antes de imprimir el dato, trata de verificar si el último caracter de la cadena es un salto de línea.

**Ejemplo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char nombre[24];
}Paciente;

int main (void) 
{
    int len;
    Paciente paciente;
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:\n");
    fgets(paciente.nombre, sizeof paciente.nombre, stdin);
    //Obtenemos la longitud del vector
    len = strlen(paciente.nombre);
    //Verificamos si el último caracter es un salto de línea
    if(paciente.nombre[len - 1] == '\n')
        //Eliminamos el salto de línea
        paciente.nombre[len - 1] = '\0';
    //Imprimimos la cadena
    printf("Los datos del paciente %s son : \n", paciente.nombre);
    return 0;
}
```

Si el usuario ingresa `RAFA`, el resultado por pantalla debería ser:

```
Los datos del paciente RAFA son :
```

Comment: Me ha encantado tu respuesta, cuando me despierta por la mañana,  pongo ese ejemplo  y te cuento, muchísimas gracias de todos modos.   Ps : aqui es 01:28 am aqui

Answer (score 1):

fgets() termina de leer el flujo de entrada cuando encuentra un ENTER (\n), este lo saca del flujo y lo almacena en la cadena, es por esto que si queremos eliminar este salto de linea, una solución es usar la función strcspn() que devuelve la posición de la cadena en donde encuentra el carácter

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char name[40];
   printf("Nombre? ");
   if (fgets(name, 40, stdin))
   {
       name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;   //buscará en la cadena name el primer match con \n y devolverá la posición en name en la cual fue encontrado el match.
       printf("Hola %s!\n", name);
   }
}
```